# Turning List<MapEntry<int, bool>> into Map<int, bool> in dart

Tags: dictionary, dart

I want to create a map with maps the numbers from 1 to 10 to count values. Currently, I do:

```
Iterable<int> spread = Iterable<int>.generate(10);
Iterable<Future<MapEntry<int, bool>>> futureEntries= spread.map((i) async {
  int level = i + 1;
  bool levelRight = await checkCountForLevel(level);
  return MapEntry(level, levelRight);
});
List<MapEntry<int, bool>> listOfEntries = await Future.wait(futureEntries);
Map<int, bool> levelCorrect = Map.fromIterable(listOfEntries);
```

However, I get the error:

> E/flutter (29690): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'MapEntry<int, bool>' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'key'

Do I have to use a different method then Map.fromIterable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I am trying to fix your solution, I just want to know if you are aware that you could do this instead?

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final levelCorrect = {
    for (var level = 1; level <= 10; level++)
      level : await checkCountForLevel(level)
  };
}
```

If you want to use your own solution, you should use [`Map.fromEntries`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Map/Map.fromEntries.html) instead of [`Map.fromIterable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterable.html).